Embarcadero Delphi IDE signature
is there a signature or identification written by IDE software (let say embarcadero Delphi) to the complied android apk or aab file ? And how I know it?
I have decompile the apk or aab android file using jadx and the results is none (but maybe I missed something)

What are you trying to accomplish, exactly?

Just want to know, if it is there, and i am optimistic it should, than a newbie programmer should warned to use community edition rather than illegally one, even for free android app before he jump to the river

Even if such a signature existed, what makes you think it would be able to identify an "illegal" copy of the IDE?

I use same technically but different use in my software, it should record the development environment
